# How to delete elements where index place not known

Tags: r, function, debugging, while-loop, set

I am trying to write a function that starts with the first element and adds the element to the number one, the result of the sum is then deleted from the set. for example we start with 1, 1 is the first element hence 1+1=2 2 gets deleted from the set and 3 now becomes the second element. Heres what I have so far but it only deletes 2 from the set and wont delete 5 and etc..

```
mynewset <- function(i, n, count) {
  x <- seq(i, n, 1)
  while(count < n) {
    m <- x[count] + count
    if(m %in% x) {
      x <- x[-which(x %in% m)]
    }  else {
      count <- n+1
    }
    count+1
  }
  return(x)
}

mynewset(1,100,1)
```

Comment: Your line `count + 1` accomplishes nothing; to increment count, you must reassign it: `count <- count + 1` ; but then it might be incremented twice...

Comment: Thank you so much!! That fixed everything. My professor and I spent one hour looking at the code trying to find the mistake and we completely missed that.

Comment: Good! And don't forget to indent your code (RStudio has the `CTRL-I` shortcut for doing it for you, if you use it (and if you don't, give it a try, it's great!), it's much easier to spot mistakes on indented code!